# Visually creating database tables with the Data Explorer

Tags: delphi, sqlite, delphi-xe3

I watched a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=416qL6is5Xw#t=26s) in relations to creating and working with databases in Delphi. The video states that you can create the database using code, the data explorer or the SQLite3 console application, but I am unable to find out how to create the database using the Data Explorer. Does anyone know a way I can go about doing this?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instructions that follow are for XE3, but they should work for XE as well.

Right-click on the `SQLite` item in the Data Explorer, and choose `New connection`.

Enter the full path to your new database file (which, of course, won't exist yet) in the `Database` edit control.

Click the `Advanced` button in the lower right corner of the dialog. Find the entry for `FailIfMissing`, and change the value from `True` to `False`, and then click the `OK` button to close the `Advanced Properties` dialog.

Click the `Test connection` button in the lower left corner of the dialog (directly across from the `Advanced` button you clicked before). You should get a dialog that says `Test connection successful`. Close the `New Connection` dialog. (If you don't get a successful test connection at this point, check the path to the database you entered; it will fail if the folder doesn't exist. It can also fail if the `SQLite3.dll` isn't on your Windows `PATH` or is the wrong version.)

To create tables, expand the Data Explorer entry for your new connection created above, so you can see the `Tables`, `Views`, and `Procedures` branches. Right-click on `Tables`, and choose `New table` from the pop-up menu.

Comment: At the moment, I only have DataSnap and Interbase in the Data Explorer. Is there a way I can add SQLite to that list?

Comment: What SKU (Starter, Professional, etc) are you using? IIRC, SQLite wasn't included in XE Starter or Professional, and therefore can't be used via `DBExpress` (which is what Data Explorer uses). (It's in XE2 and XE3 Pro, but not in Starter, BTW.) There are third-party components that will allow you to use SQLite, but you can't use Data Explorer to work with it. (If you use FireFox, there's an SQLite Manager add-in that works pretty well and is free; it adds a new button to the toolbar that opens an IDE for SQLite.)

Comment: I believe I have the Ultimate Edition.

Comment: "You believe"? :-) `Help->About`, and look at the `Product Status` near the bottom of the dialog. It should say `Product Status: Registered`, and right below that show the SKU (mine in XE3 clearly says `Professional`). If you have `Ultimate` and don't have `SQLite`, you didn't install something and need to re-run the installer to include the missing pieces.

Comment: I've re-run the installer several times now; DBXPool, DBXTrace and IBToGo have appeared in my Data Explorer. I don't understand why they're just randomly appearing and why SQLite isn't there ... P.S. I have XE3 Ultimate Edition.

Comment: You should probably open a new question on that, then; it's a totally separate topic from this one. (Make sure you tag it `delphi`, `delphi-xe3`, and `dbexpress`.) You can also open a free support case with [Embarcadero](http://support.embarcadero.com) for an installation issue. They're actually fairly quick at responding.