# Delphi lightweight Database components/ engine

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, data-storage

Im working on an application for a friend and I want to store some information.
Its not huge, its like a dvd collection he wants to keep track of.

What im looking for is a way to store his data. Like a database but since its not much that has to be stored I wondered if there are any components out there to do this.

Like create tables etc.

I've been looking around but didnt find much. Any thoughts here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delphi XE3 includes [SqLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) support (using [DbExpress](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/DbExpress_Framework)) which is perfect for this kind of tasks.

Try these links

- [Connecting to a SQLite Database](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Tutorial:_Connecting_to_a_SQLite_Database_%28Delphi%29)
- [Using a SQLite database in VCL and FMX apps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=416qL6is5Xw)
- [Visually creating database tables with the Data Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057789/visually-creating-database-tables-with-the-data-explorer)
- [Delphi Programming Tutorial #76 - SQLite support in Delphi XE3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXwQxkr9BZg)

Also you can try [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) which is [supported](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2CBJiUeeJo) by [DbExpress](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/DbExpress_Framework) as well.

Comment: Ok this looks really good, i'll accept it as answer, but can you tell me how I can make sure this would work on another pc also, im very new to this, and I dont know how to do it. I want it all to run local. So the system would have to be on his computer. Any way to integrate this into my own software?

Comment: To run the same application in another machine, you must distribute the  Sqlite related files (sqlite3.dll), the database file (.db) and your app files (exe, dll and so on). Try following the tutorials about Delphi and Sqlite and if you have any *specific* doubt you can ask another question.

Comment: Or, you can optionally get [`FireDAC`](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/29318) if you have Enterprise, Ultimate or Architect editions of Delphi XE3. It [`supports SQLite`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/firedac/Connect_to_SQLite_database.html) database natively [+1]